# Is it possible to clone a git repository, and split the clone repo, keeping track of the changes from original repo?

Tags: git, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

This might be somewhat unusual, but say I have a **git** repository A:

```
A/project1/...   
A/project2/...   
A/project3/...
```

and clone this repository to B:

```
B/project1/...   
B/project2/...   
B/project3/...
```

What I want to do is to somehow split the project folders and their contents into individual units. It does not really matter if the unit is a *branch*, a *repository* or whatever, the important thing here is that I need to be able to efficiently fetch changes from repository A upstream, and track in B's units.

*Why?*

I want to use Jenkins and only build the projects if they contain changes, and Jenkins supports this for a single repository or branch. However, I can not change the original repository A. Alternative solutions are of course also very welcome.

Comment: precisely what submodules are for

Comment: @g19fanatic I thought submodules were for the opposite scenario, not for splitting a repository into parts *and* keep tracking upstream changes. Can you elaborate with a full example? :)

Answer (score 1):

[Sparse checkouts](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) may be of help here.

1. You need to clone the repository A.
2. You then have to configure sparse checkout (after cloning):

   - `git config core.sparsecheckout true`
   - `echo project1/ > .git/info/sparse-checkout`
3. Then you need to call `git read-tree -m -u HEAD`

**Notes**

However the sparse checkout is not truly independent. Let us say you want only `project1`. Changes introduced by `project2` or `project3` in your case will suggest that your sparse checkout has changed.

**References**

- [Checkout sub directories in git](http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts/)

Comment: Three simple steps -- I like it, thanks! :) So, this creates individual repositories for each project. Will **git fetch** work correctly in these repositories, i.e. only track changes in the current project? So, if there is a change in *project A*, will a **git fetch** in *project B*'s repo behave as if there were no changes? Does it have a space overhead?

Comment: I do not know, please give it a try and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I finally tested this, and since git downloads the entire tree for the whole repository, one can not rely on changes to the whole repository with sparse checkouts to detect changes in a single project.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but for some reason, it hasn't been accepted yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3385465

Comment: Looks great, thanks :) However, I am reluctant to accept it as the answer, since it does not solve the use case... Agreed?

Comment: No problem, I do not care about points/accepted answer but rather about good content on the internet, therefore I will delete most of my previous comments. Have a nice day.